# Captcha in MEAN js

Tags: node.js, captcha, mean-stack, meanjs

I need to use Captcha in MEAN js login. I need the simplest possible way to make it work. I saw [Visual Captcha](https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha-node/) but I'm not able to understand where should I use it in the MEAN js application.

I need an offline captcha solution on MEAN js app. I plan to deploy it on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google recaptcha with external script file in mean stack page. There is a js code.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api

Just follow this.

> ````
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>       var onloadCallback = function() {
>         grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
>           'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
>         });
>       };
>     </script>   </head>   <body>
>     <form action="?" method="POST">
>       <div id="html_element"></div>
>       <br>
>       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
>     </form>
>     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
>         async defer>
>     </script>   </body> ```
> ````